# Need Assistance with NordLocker and BitLocker Interaction Issue

Tags: windows, usb, encryption, bitlocker

I'm encountering a perplexing issue related to NordLocker and BitLocker on my USB drive, and I'm seeking some guidance and assistance to resolve it. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to get this sorted out, and it's becoming a bit of a roadblock for me. Here are the details:

The Situation:

- I encrypted my USB drive with both Windows BitLocker and NordLocker.
- I recently moved to a new Windows device and removed BitLocker encryption from my USB using my BitLocker recovery key.
- However, when attempting to open the NordLocker locker on the USB drive, I'm receiving a message stating that I do not have permission to access the files.
- I do not have access to the original device anymore.
- I wasn't able to test NordLocker on the new device before removing BitLocker, I went straight to disabling it on the new device. NordLocker support had me copying the locker file from the USB to the C: drive, which I tried. I ended up getting a File Access Denied error stating 'You require permission from Everyone to make changes...'. When going to Properties on the locker file, there is no 'Security' tab.

Steps Taken So Far:

- I've verified that BitLocker is fully disabled on the USB drive. The status indicates "Protection Off" and "Fully Decrypted."
- I've restarted my computer and attempted to access the files in NordLocker, but the issue persists.
- I've contacted both NordLocker and Microsoft support, but they each directed me to the other, and I'm stuck in a bit of a support loop.

My Request for Help:

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with NordLocker and BitLocker interaction?
Is there a way to ensure that BitLocker has been completely removed from the USB drive, even though it says it's off?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Please keep in mind that I've already contacted both support teams, but the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: You have verified BitLocker protection was disabled, so your permission issue, seems to be completely caused by NordLocker. Seems like the original device might be the solution to disable whatever protections NordLocker does then renable it on the new device. NordLocker appears to protect files in the cloud it’s not clear what it’s doing to the file system, unfamiliar, with third-party file system encryption options like NordLocker

Comment: Did NordLocker work on the new device before you removed BitLocker? Bitlocker and NordLocker work at different layers, so they shouldn't interfere with each other. Do you have filesystem read permissions to the .locker file? Like can you open it in notepad or copy it to your C: drive for example? You may just need to take ownership/add permissions for your user account on your new device first

Comment: @Ramhound: That's what I suspected as well. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the original device anymore and NordLocker support seems to believe it's a Windows fault.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: I wasn't able to test NordLocker on the new device before removing BitLocker, I went straight to disabling it on the new device.

NordLocker support had me copying the locker file from the USB to the C: drive, which I tried. I ended up getting a File Access Denied error stating 'You require permission from Everyone to make changes...'. When going to Properties on the locker file, there is no 'Security' tab.

Comment: @supernord The drive's filesystem is probably FAT32 if there is no security tab (right-click the drive in explorer > properties > general tab > File system). There is no permissions structure on FAT32, so the "access denied" messages most likely come from windows having issues reading the drive. Try booting into safe mode (in case some weird software is causing the issue) and attempt to copy the file again. OR check for corruption with `chkdsk E:` with the right drive letter.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale - FAT32 doesn’t support file permissions so that’s extremely unlikely

Comment: @Cpt.Whale You're right, it is FAT32. Running `chkdsk` says 'Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.' Booting into safe mode I run into the same issue. Same with booting into safe mode with command prompt, it skips the files with permission errors when copying.

Comment: @supernord maybe you'll have more luck with a file recovery program, or something that can do a block-based copy? like dd-for-windows can create a mountable file with `dd if=\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0 of=c:\temp\usb.img bs=1M --size --progress` for example. Try copying that file off using another computer too if possible, just in case something like antivirus is causing issues (though usually safe mode would usually fix)

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I was able to copy the .locker file to my c: drive using dd-for-windows. When attempting to open it in NordLocker it says 'Please run NordLocker setup if you cannot open any lockers'. I've contacted NordLocker support about this.